# sharepoint 2010 Remote Blob Storage , RemoteBlobStorageSettings is false

Tags: 2010, powershell, remote-blob-storage

Im following this article for enable RBS on sharepoint 2010 i thinks its best article for that after a lot of search :
http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=1280

when I try the  Step 8 – Enable RBS on the Content Database
with those command :

```
$contentDB = Get-SPContentDatabase –WebApplication <weburl>
$rbsSettings = $contentDB.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbsSettings.Enable()
$rbsSettings.SetActiveProviderName($rbsSettings.GetProviderNames()[0])
```

on enable command i face an exception, and when I try this command its gives me false :
`$rbsSettings.Installed()` ------False

any one can help me to continue enable RBS with this article 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I run the file "RBS_X64" and go with wizard with full functionality then the command :

$rbsSettings.Installed() gives me True

then I can enable and its work fine

Comment: You should not install the RBS client library by double clicking the RBS_X64.msi (which will run the wizard). Instead, you must use the msiexec command to run the msi file. This is because running the wizard will set certain default values that are not recommended for SharePoint. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx In fact, in the article you are referencing in your question, they also mention this.